# How to color-code a 3D point plot

Tags: plotting, color, visualization

I am doing a Finite Difference Method for 3D heat diffusion, so I need my ListPointPlot3D to be color coded on a range from deep red to deep blue depending on the temperature of the point.

My instinct is that I should have a fourth dimension to my list of points describing the temperature at that point, e.g {1,1,1,40} would describe a temperature of 40 at the first point in my partition, and so on. Is there a plotting option that lets me range the color of a point based on this 4th parameter?

If not, do you see any other way I can do this in Mathematica? I have tried `ColorFunction`, but I don't want my temperature to depend on the spatial dimensions x,y,z, I want it to depend on a fourth dimension "w" where the temperatures exist.

Many thanks

Comment: `ColorFunction -> Function[{x,y,z}, Hue[z]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1];

(data = Append @@@
    ({RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 3}], 
       RandomReal[{0, 100}, 10]} //
      Transpose)) // Grid
```

[image]

```
n = 1;
Graphics3D[{AbsolutePointSize[6],
 {Blend[{Blue, Red}, Rescale[Last[#], {0, 100}]],
 Point[Most[#]], Text[n++, Most[#], {2, 2}]} & /@ data}]
```

[image]

Comment: I'd probably use `MapIndexed[]` with `Text[]` for the labeling myself.

Comment: Thanks Bob, couldn't be more to the point!